# Would a Necromantic Selection and Angel of Glory’s Rise combo work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I’m trying to kill all of my opponents creatures but still have most of mine stay alive. To that end, most of the creatures in my deck are human.

I have a [Angel of Glory's Rise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngel%5d%2b%5bof%5d%2b%5bGlory%27s%5d%2b%5bRise%5d) on the battlefield, and cast [Necromantic Selection](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNecromantic%20Selection%5d) to destroy all creatures. I use the second part of Necromantic Selection's effect to return the Angel to the battlefield. Would the Angel enter and then exile itself? Would the rest of its ability still resolve?

Comment: What do you mean "by would it work"?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're expecting to accomplish and what concerns you about whether it might not work?

Comment: The angels ETB ability exiles all zombies on the battlefield and then returns all humans from the graveyard to the battlefield. Necromantic selection destroys all creatures and returns a creature put in the graveyard this way to the battlefield, the creature enters as a black zombie. I’m wondering if the second part of the angels ability would go off or if it would enter and then just exile itself.

Comment: I’m trying to kill all of my opponents creatures but still have most of mine stay alive

Comment: Then ask that, don't just say would a combo of two cards work, ask for what you want the combo to do, and ask if that would work.

Comment: @ikegami Your edit changed the question. OP never intended to cast Glory's Rise as part of this, they intended to use Selection's reanimate Glory's Rise.

Comment: @Andrew, Already fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to:
 - Play a large assortment of Humans
 - Play Necromantic Selection to destroy all creatures
 - Choose to return Angel of Glory's Rise to play, getting all your humans Back.

Resulting in having significant board presence, the answer is yes-ish.

Since the ability of Angel's of Glory's Rise is one sentence with multiple clauses, the entire effect will resolve. You would exile the angel, and then return all humans from your graveyard to the battlefield. Inefficient, but it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "second part" of the ability will "go off" and have the effect you desire.

The Angel will indeed exile itself, but that doesn't prevent the rest of the ability from resolving. An ability on the stack is not affected by its source ceasing to exist. The ability will resolve or continue to resolve normally.

> 112.7a Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack independently of its source. Destruction or removal of the source after that time won’t affect the ability. [...]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would work if I understand what you want but you are somewhat unclear.

1. Necromantic Selection destroys all creatures then returns Angel of Glory's Rise to the battlefield.
2. Angel of Glory's Rise triggers, exiling itself because it is a zombie then brings back any humans in your graveyard.

However if you just want to destroy all your opponent's cards, why not use [In Garruk's Wake](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIn%5d%2b%5bGarruk%27s%5d%2b%5bWake%5d) Two more mana, less of one color, and does not rely on you having specific creatures, or [River's Rebuke](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRiver%27s%5d%2b%5bRebuke%5d) if it's one opponent, you play blue, you just want to clear their field and don't care where things go. Another common tactic is [Mycosynth Lattice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMycosynth%20Lattice%5d) and [Hurkyl's Recall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHurkyl%27s%5d%2b%5bRecall%5d), eight mana for the two of them mostly colorless and returns one player's entire field to their hand.

Comment: Or if you want mono white, you could just cast Angel of Glory's Rise and Shields of Velis Vel targetting your opponent in order to exile everything they have.

Comment: @Antimony Very true, though based on the two cards, OP we know already they are in black and white, sounds like Innistrad humans based on color and race, and the angel.